# HTML Page Scraping

Tags: c#, html, ajax, screen-scraping

What's the best way to scrape a web page that has AJAX/dynamic loading of data?

For example: scraping a webpage that presents 20 images on load, but when a user scroll down the page it loads more images (sort of like Facebook). In such a case how do you scrape all the images, not just the first 20?

Answer (score 2):

Use a tool such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to inspect the web request that is done when loading more items.

Then replicate the request in your code.

---

**Update (thanks to [pguardiario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/966023/pguardiario) ofr his comment):**

Note that Wireshark is a low level network capture tool that offers a great deal of detail about the traffic (packets being exchanged, DNS lookps, and so on), and may be painful to use in such scenario, where you only wish to see the HTTP Requests.

So, you're better off using Fiddler, or a similar tool in a browser (ex: Chrome's Network inspect panel).

Comment: Fiddler yes, but wireshark would be a pain. Chrome's network inspect panel will do the job.

Comment: @pguardiario yes, that's also a great tool

Answer (score 2):

This is something that not even the major search engines have mastered yet. It's called "[event-driven crawling](http://www.net-security.org/dl/articles/Crawling_Ajax_driven_Web_2.0.pdf)".

Google even has a guide on what to do to [help them crawl your ajax sites better](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/)

Best thing would be to read some [open source crawlers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Open-source_crawlers) and see what they do. But your chances of crawling even 80% are slim at best, unless you have a specific target in mind.

There are also some interesting reads at [crawljax](http://crawljax.com/documentation/publications/)

Basically, You should try looking for scripts and checking if they make any ajax calls, then determine what kind of parameters they take and make repeat calls with incremented/decremented parameter values. This only works if the parameters have a logical pattern, such as being numbers, single letters etc. It also depends on whether you're targeting a known site or just sending it into the wild. If you know your target you can inspect it's DOM and customize your code for greater accuracy as mentioned by wolf.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

[Crawljax](http://crawljax.com) is open source and can dynamically crawl Ajax-based content.